# Swift Removing Connection to Navigation View Controller after Action

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue, xcode-storyboard

I have a storyboard setup where a user opens the application and is brought to a social login view. If the user has not registered before, he is brought to a registration navigation view and if the user has, then that user is brought to the tabbed view which holds the apps true functionality. The issue I am having is that when a user has to register, after the registration, the tabbed view opens with a navigation that allows to go back to the registration page. How can I remove that functionality from happening? After a registration the tabbed view should not have any relationship with the registration navigation view. Is there a certain segue method that would achieve this? See storyboard below.

[image: storyboard]

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this,
One way is to create a custom UIBarButtonItem and assign it to the leftBarButtonItem of the navigationItem of your tabbed view controller

```
 var customButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Action, target: self, action: "customAction:")
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customButton
```

Write code in `customAction:` to segue into the scene you want to go on button click.

Note: There are a number UIBarButtonItem init methods that you can use to customize the appearance of the button

Comment: I don't believe you understand my problem. When I click "Done" on the registration navigation controller, my segue brings me to my tabbed view controller with a "Back" button appearing allowing the user to go back to the registration navigation controller. I don't want this "Back" button to appear and there should be no relationship from the tabbed controller to the navigation controller after a registration occurs.

Comment: In viewWillAppear of your tabbed view controller set self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil if you want to prevent the back button from appearing.